# Original thread lost because of changed reference

Tags: java, android, multithreading, reference

In my android app I'm trying to extend the Thread class to easy pass my values between the original thread and a another one. So I can easily update my UI.

To do this I extended the Thread class:

```
public class ThreadUpdateUI extends Thread {
    AppCombatActivityExtended activity;
    Map<?,?> values;

    public ThreadUpdateUI(AppCombatActivityExtended activity, Map<?,?> values){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public void UpdateUI(Map<?,?> values){
        this.activity.UIThreadFinished(values);
    }

    public Map<?,?> GetValues()
    {
        return this.values;
    }
}
```

Not only did I extend Threads, but I also extended the class for Activity so I have a main function I can call in every activity to update my UI:

```
public class AppCombatActivityExtended extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void UIThreadFinished(Map<?,?> values){}
}
```

In my activity I use the ThreadUpdateUI class to run a thread in which I can pass all my own values to use in the other thread:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCombatActivityExtended {
    static final String carlooking_key = "text_carlooking";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //init views
        final TextView text_carlooking = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text_carlooking);

        //init parameters for thread
        HashMap<String, String> UIThreadParameters = new HashMap<>();
        UIThreadParameters.put(carlooking_key, text_carlooking.getText().toString().replace(".", ""));

        //ThreadUpdateUI
        ThreadUpdateUI TU_UI = new ThreadUpdateUI(this, UIThreadParameters) {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Integer counter = 0;
                    while (true) {
                        sleep(1000);
                        Map values = GetValues();
                        String text = values.get(carlooking_key).toString();
                        text += "_test";
                        Map result = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        result.put(carlooking_key, text);

                        UpdateUI(result);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        TU_UI.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void UIThreadFinished(Map<?, ?> values) {
        super.UIThreadFinished(values);
        final TextView text_carlooking = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text_carlooking);
        text_carlooking.setText(values.get(carlooking_key).toString());

    }
}
```

My code crashes at:

```
UpdateUI(result);
```

Saying: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

In my trace I can see the following:

```
at MainActivity.UIThreadFinished(MainActivity.java:56)  
at ThreadUpdateUI.UpdateUI(ThreadUpdateUI.java:21)
at MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:42)
```

Which could indicate that the reference changed in my ThreadUpdateUI causing to call ThreadUpdateUIFinished in a different thread than the original.

Is it possible to make this code return to the original thread to update my UI in a loop?

Comment: Use `runonuithread` in `UIThreadFinished ` method

Comment: Oo I see this way I can always return to the original thread. Thanks! I was so close heh